# Django Update User form photo saves but doesnt update in the site itself

Tags: python, django

So I am trying my hand out at my first django project on my own after tutorials, and I am trying to add an update user profile page. The username and email update perfectly fine, but when i try to update the profile picture, it doesnt update.Even though the file is saved in my media folder.

forms.py:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email')

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('image',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    profile = Profile(user=user)

    user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'user': user, 'profile': profile, 'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<h3 class="display-3 mb-3">
    {{ user.username }}
</h3>
<p>
    {{ user.bio }}
</p>

<br>
<img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="ok">
<hr>

<hr>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend>Profile Info</legend>
        {{ user_form|crispy }}
        {{ profile_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

If you need any more code i will update the question.
What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: It sounds like the image is not showing in your template, if I understand correctly.  Can you share some template code?

Comment: Hmm, the problem may be how you are serving static files.  Do images show up anywhere else in your app?

Comment: @sc_props no i havent used images anywhere else yet except for this page. The default profile picture shows up perfectly fine but the edited one doesnt.

Comment: The edited/updated photo doesn't show even after page refresh?  And you can confirm that it saves to the database, and is visible in the admin?

Comment: @sc_props i haven't checked the admin panel but it does save in the respective folder

Comment: @sc_props another update. I just saw that in the form, where it shows the current profile picture, it is showing the one i changed it to. the only place its not updating is the website itself, like what the user sees

Comment: If you have registered your `Profile` model in the admin, check to see if you can update and see updated images there.  If they update there AND the updated image shows in your template, that might narrow down the problem.

Comment: @sc_props i just did that and saw that the updated profile picture is showing up but only in the form, not actually in the template itself. This is really confusing

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `profile = Profile(user=user)`. Are you trying to get a model object here or a form class?  Or something else?  Could it be missing something, like `Profile.objects.get(user=user)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `instance=request.user.profile` from your bound ProfileUpdateForm. And perhaps adding `profile.image = request.FILES['image']` and `profile.save()` after your `profile_form.is_valid()` check. Or a combination of the two.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I believe the instance is a required argument. But you may have to try the second piece of advice which is to assign the file to the profile image field and save the profile manually.